# jQuery - Many toggle sliders, only one visible at the time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four jquery sliders in a page with these scripts:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#information").click(function(){
    $("#information_show").slideToggle("medium");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu").click(function(){
    $("#menu_slide").slideToggle("medium");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#books").click(function(){
    $("#books_toggle").slideToggle("medium");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#content").click(function(){
    $("#content_div").slideToggle("medium");
  });
});
```

So for example when I click on the div `#information` the `#information_toggle` is visible. I wounder if there is any way to make the sliders only show one at once.

Example: When click on `#books`, the `#books_toogle` show. Now when click on `#menu` the `#menu_slide` shows, at the same time the `#menu_slide` shows `#books_toggle` toogle/close automatic. So only one hidden div will show at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to see your html, but it is easy to do this in an ugly way:

```
$("#information").click(function(){
    $("#information_show").slideToggle();
    $("menu_slide, books_toggle, content_div").slideUp();
});
```

However, a much prettier way to do this would be with classes:

```
$(".slider").on('click', function () {
    var $assocDiv = $(".slider_show").eq($(this).index));
    $assocDiv.slideToggle();
    $(".slider_show").not($assocDiv).slideUp();      
});
```

Regardless, you only need one `$(document).ready`, which can just be written as `$(`, and `'medium'` is already the default animation speed.

Comment: I dont really understand the second example, do you mean to give all the divs that toggle the class .slider_show and all the buttons to click to make the content toggle .slider? Is that correct?

Comment: Ok thats maybe better becuse less code. I have a little problem with the code, I do think your code is correct but the earlier sliders was executed/initialized becuse they was loaded into the page, they look like this "$(document).on("reload" ,function() {" in the beginning of the script instead of "$(document).ready(function(){", do you maybe know how to initialize this script like the others? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Can you create an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: In jsfiddle its impossible to load in content from external sites. I try to explain, the sliders gets loaded in to the page after page have finish loaded via a select/dropdown with this code "$containerDiv.load( "external_page.html #div_containing_the_sliders" , function(){$(document).trigger("ready reload");});" so when load in elements I use "$(document).on("ready reload" ,function() {" to execute the jquery elements (otherwise they should not run becuse page already finish loaded when content loads in). In code "$(".slider").on('click', function () {" I dont know what to change.

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.slider', function () {`

Comment: Thats not working. I must execute the script by using "ready reload" becuse at the same time the dropdown/selectelement loads in a div (containing elements) all those elements must be executed to run, and they gets executed by "$(document).on("ready reload" ,function() {". So example, if you see the post above this by "Back in a Flash" that code will work by changing "$(document).ready(function(){" to "$(document).on("ready reload". The problem is I dont know how to do this in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Though it should be posted on CodeReview(imho), here's what you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var last, last2;
    $("#information").click(function () {
        $("#information_show").slideToggle("medium");
        if (last != '#information_show' && last != last2) $(last).slideToggle("medium");
        last2 = last;
        last = '#information_show';
    });
    $("#menu").click(function () {
        $("#menu_slide").slideToggle("medium");
        if (last != '#menu_slide' && last != last2) $(last).slideToggle("medium");
        last2 = last;
        last = '#menu_slide';
    });
    $("#books").click(function () {
        $("#books_toggle").slideToggle("medium");
        if (last != '#books_toggle' && last != last2) $(last).slideToggle("medium");
        last2 = last;
        last = '#books_toggle';
    });
    $("#content").click(function () {
        $("#content_div").slideToggle("medium");
        if (last != '#content_div' && last != last2) $(last).slideToggle("medium");
        last2 = last;
        last = '#content_div';
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that if toggle one div, then try to close that div by click on the same button again, the div will close then automatic open again.

Comment: Do you maybe know how to fix that? The script works fine except that.

Comment: @Wobot At this point of time, a jsfiddle would surely b welcome.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6MG5w/ Click at a headline, then click on same headline again, then click on another headline.

Comment: @Wobot You can use `accordion` as @mooseman suggested. You would have just three lines in your JS code -> [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6MG5w/1/). Otherwise, check the latest edit